# How do I make the arrow reach two tags in mermaid?

Tags: mermaid

I have created this flowchart using mermaid.

```
flowchart TD
id1(( ))
id1-->Tag1
Tag1-->Tag2
    subgraph Tag2
    id2(( ))
    id2-->Tag3
    Tag3-->Tag4
    subgraph Tag4
    id3(( ))
    id3-->Tag5
    Tag5-->Tag6
    Tag6-->Tag7
    end
    Tag7-->Tag8
end
    Tag8-->Tag9
```

[image]

My problem is that the arrow from `Tag1` to `Tag2` isn't long enough. How do I go about with it? I tried the below, but the connection should be from `Tag1` to `Tag2`, not to the beginning of the black circle after `Tag2`.

```
id1(( ))
id1-->Tag1
Tag1-->id2(( )) # Tag1-->Tag2 in original
    subgraph Tag2
    id2(( ))
    id2-->Tag3
    Tag3-->Tag4
    subgraph Tag4
    id3(( ))
    id3-->Tag5
    Tag5-->Tag6
    Tag6-->Tag7
    end
    Tag7-->Tag8
end
    Tag8-->Tag9
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you first following code on [stackedit](https://stackedit.io/app#)

````
```mermaid
flowchart TD
id1(( ))
id1-->Tag1
Tag1-->Tag2
    subgraph Tag2
    id2(( ))
    id2-->Tag3
    Tag3-->Tag4
    subgraph Tag4
    id3(( ))
    id3-->Tag5
    Tag5-->Tag6
    Tag6-->Tag7
    end
    Tag7-->Tag8
end
    Tag8-->Tag9
```
````

And its result as follows:

[image]

I think this is what you want, and it could be the problem of the mermaid viewer.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. DIdn't know about stackedit!

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer if it's the one you needed.